# Find the files between two folder dates in linux?

Tags: files, grep, find, search, timestamps

I need to find the folder names along with the file names which has my string in their contents. I am in this directory "`/data/queue/data`" and I have lot of folders in the same directory and inside those each folders, I have various files.

Below are the folders in this directory "`/data/queue/data`" and each of those folders has various files in it.

```
david@machineA:/data/queue/data$ ls -lrth
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 18:58 1428800400
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 19:58 1428804000
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 20:58 1428807600
```

I want to run a command from this directory only - "`/data/queue/data`" but it should only find the files inside folder whose timestamp is from `April 13th 3 AM to April 13th 9 AM`.

Below is the command I have which will recursively find the files inside all the folders but how should I make sure that it should only find files from `April 13th 3 AM to April 13th 9 AM` folders?

```
david@machineA:/data/queue/data$ grep -rl "pcV6URY" /data/queue/data
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
touch -d"April 13 3 AM" file1
touch -d"April 13 9 AM" file2
find . -newer file1 ! -newer file2 -exec grep -l "pcV6URY" {} +
rm file1 file2
```

#### How it works

`find` can work directly with times but `touch` handles human-style dates better:

- `touch -d"April 13 3 AM" file1; touch -d"April 13 9 AM" file2`

  This creates two files to mark the beginning and end of the time range.
- `find . -newer file1 ! -newer file2 -exec grep -l "pcV6URY" {} +`

  This finds files newer than `file1` but not newer than `file2`.  For all such files, it runs `grep` on them to see if they contain your string.